# c# 2nd dropdownlist fail retain the value when submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        filldropdown(dllselection.SelectedValue);
        Code.Enabled = true;
        if(dllselection.SelectedValue=="")
        {
            Code.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```

i think there something wrong with the page load,my 2nd dropdownlist is depend on 1st dropdownlist selection.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"  style="color:black" >Main Category</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dllselection" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" required>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="HR" Value="M_1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="IT" Value="M_2"></asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Text="Maintenance" Value="M_3"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Training" style="color:black" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sub Category</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Code" Enabled="false" onchange="javascript:return dropdown(this);" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  ValidationGroup="G1" required></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        </div>
```

everytime i submit pass data to database,the value for the 2nd dropdownlist always the 1st value.

```
 public void filldropdown(string item)
{

        int loggedUserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["loggedUserID"]);
        List<BOL.UserInfo> userslist = new UserInfos().List();
        BOL.UserInfo loggeduser = userslist.Where(x => x.UserID == loggedUserID).FirstOrDefault();
        //  int ID = 10;

        List<e_request> role = new e_requests().dropdownlistG(loggeduser.SUBSIDIARY_CD, item);
        Code.DataSource = role;
        Code.DataTextField = "CAT_DESC";
        Code.DataValueField = "SUB_CAT";
        Code.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: try to load method in !Ispostback

Comment: you need to add onindexchanged method to the first drop downlist, then within that event ,you have to fill the second drop down list, then submit, you need to add a new event to the fist drop down list

Answer (score 2):

You can filling drop down on postback which you should not if you want to keep selection. use `!Page.IsPostBack` instead of `Page.IsPostBack`

Change

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
```

To

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
```

On more thing you may need to put condition out side !Page.IsPostBack as you would need it to be executed on postback

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   filldropdown(dllselection.SelectedValue);
}

Code.Enabled = true;
if(dllselection.SelectedValue=="")
{
        Code.Enabled = false;
}
```

Also note you may need to fill the second dropdown on [SelectedIndexChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of dllselection and need to set `AutoPostBack` of `dllselection` true.

Comment: not working,2nd dropdownlist no show any data and enable="false";

Comment: show us code of filldropdown and also is Code a drop down?

Comment: What is dllselection.SelectedValue passed to filldropdown, what is count of role?

Comment: dllselection.SelectedValue  is correct when pass to database,2nd dropdownlist got problem only

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

if (!IsPostBack)
            {

```
            if (dllselection.SelectedValue == "")
            {
                Code.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Code.Enabled = true;
                filldropdown(dllselection.SelectedValue);  
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="logList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="itemSelected">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
       filldropdown(dllselection.SelectedValue);       
       Code.Enabled = true;
        if(dllselection.SelectedValue=="")
        {
            Code.Enabled = false;
        }
}

}
```

Comment: 2nd data still the 1st choice during submit

Answer (score 0):

Try to Load Method in

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        filldropdown(dllselection.SelectedValue);
        Code.Enabled = true;
        if(dllselection.SelectedValue=="")
        {
            Code.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

you need to fill the second dropdown on `SelectedIndexChange` of dllselection and need to set `AutoPostBack = true` of dllselection .

Comment: 2nd dropdownlist empty data

Answer (score 0):

add  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dllselection_SelectedIndexChanged" to my 1st dropdownlist.

```
 protected void dllselection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dllselection.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            Code.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Code.Enabled = true;
            //fill Code
            filldropdown(dllselection.SelectedValue);

        }
    }
```